# Accessing drupal database using JSON web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, drupal-6

hi i m new to drupal(6) and please tell me,
**how to use node create from Services to access drupal database** from my mobile app built using JS,AJAX,JQUERY MOBILE..

i want to insert some data  like name,address,price into drupal table from my mobile app using node create service.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        data: {"method" : "", "parameters required"},
        success:function(data){
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Some error occured");
        }
    });
```

use the above to allow web service to access drupal DB.